# How to align windows when they are very near

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have an application with some small windows on the screen. I would like to align them to each other, so when I move one close enough, it will automatically be align with the other. Helping me positioning and size them all. 
How can I know the position of other windows when there isn't a parent window? Is it possible to know it even if they are different process (applications)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure what you mean but the following trick is what I use for dynamic layout and it gives me full control over anything, you just need to play around with it and you can easily get the distance between two windows.
This code is copied from a windows phone app but it is easily understood.

```
        width = Convert.ToInt32(Window.Current.Bounds.Width);//gets window width
        height = Convert.ToInt32(Window.Current.Bounds.Height);// gets window height
        double dist Math.Abs(Btn1.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty) - Btn2.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty) + Btn2.Width);
```

note first two lines are only in order to have the proportions right in every single movement and resize you do, you can keep it all proportional to the window size.